# GCC plugin: copying function's arguments

Tags: c, gcc, instrumentation, gcc-plugins

I develop a GCC plugin that instruments the applications being compiled. The applications are written in C and are built with GCC 4.7 (4.8 and 4.9 are also an option) on an x86 Linux system.

My plugin implements a compilation pass which is placed after "ssa" standard pass and operates on GIMPLE representation. Among other things, I need to implement the following but currently cannot figure out how to do it correctly.

When processing a C function, I need to insert the code at its beginning that copies its arguments to the local variables I create, for future processing.

My first naive implementation looked as follows:

```
tree p;
gimple_seq seq = NULL;
gimple_stmt_iterator gsi = gsi_start_bb(single_succ(ENTRY_BLOCK_PTR));

for (p = DECL_ARGUMENTS(current_function_decl); p; p = DECL_CHAIN(param)) {
    tree copy_par;
    copy_par = create_tmp_var(TREE_TYPE(p), NULL);
    add_referenced_var(copy_par);
    copy_par = make_ssa_name(copy_par, NULL);
    g = gimple_build_assign(copy_par, p);
    SSA_NAME_DEF_STMT(copy_par) = g;
    gimple_seq_add_stmt_without_update (&seq, g);
    ... // more processing here
}
...
gsi_insert_seq_before (&gsi, seq, GSI_SAME_STMT);
```

This way, however, an invalid assignment of the parameter declaration to a variable is created according to a dump:

```
gimple_assign <parm_decl, D.2206_11, par, NULL>
```

`D.2206_11` corresponds to the local variable I created, `par` - the argument of the function I want to copy.

GCC crashes at some later pass as a result, trying to process this added statement. I suppose this is because `p` is not *the variable* holding the value of the respective argument but *a declaration* of that variable. Is it this way? And how to get that variable?

I tried using `gimple_build_assign_with_ops(NOP_EXPR, copy_par, p, NULL_TREE)` instead of `gimple_build_assign()` but it did not do either. GCC still crashes at the same place. I can provide the backtrace but I feel I am just missing something fundamental.

I also looked at traversal of trees starting from `TYPE_ARG_TYPES (TREE_TYPE (current_function_decl))` and further via `TREE_CHAIN(...)` but that seems to give the types of the arguments rather than the respective variables.

So, the question is, how to add copying of the function's arguments properly.

**Note**
Perhaps, this could be done with the help of MELT or GCC Python plugin, but in this project, I need to perform all transformations of the code using only what GCC itself provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that copying of the arguments works with GCC 4.8 and 4.9 but not with 4.7. [Here is the code](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr-aux/blob/master/compile-time/src/kmodule-test.cpp) that works for me now (`instrument_fentry()` performs the copying).

To avoid the copies being removed at the later compile passes, I made the corresponding variables volatile.

In addition, if there were no SSA_NAME with default definition statement specified for a given parameter (see `SSA_NAME_IS_DEFAULT_DEF()`), I added such SSA_NAMEs with GIMPLE_NOPs as the defining statements.

This has worked OK with GCC 4.8 and 4.9 so far, so it looks like a bug in GCC 4.7 or some change of rules between GCC 4.7 and 4.8. I could not pinpoint the exact commit though.

Comment: `get_or_create_ssa_default_def`?

Comment: @MarcGlisse: You mean using `get_or_create_ssa_default_def` instead of inserting GIMPLE_NOPs by hand? Yes, may be. Saves some typing.